# How to make JS & CSS inline work for eBay template?

Tags: javascript, html, css

How is it possible to make the JS work in this:
http://jsfiddle.net/JoshSalway/3vVVc/

```
<script type="text/javascript" id="SCRIPT_12">var arICImages0 = new Array(4);   arICImages0[0] = "http://easydealsonline.info/prod/images/281259.jpg";arICImages0[1] = "http://easydealsonline.info/prod/images/281260.jpg";arICImages0[2] = "http://easydealsonline.info/prod/images/281261.jpg";arICImages0[3] = "http://easydealsonline.info/prod/images/281262.jpg";        function swapIC0(n) {        document['ICImage0'].src = arICImages0[n];    }
                    </script>
```

Like this:
http://www.ebay.com.au/itm/New-Stage-Light-Truss-Tripod-Lighting-Stand-Rack-/261352049121

I copied code with SnappySnippet. Trying to re-create similar JS on this side. what is missing to make "javascript:swapIC0(0);" work?

How do you make JS & CSS work inline?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an updated fiddle that should work - http://jsfiddle.net/3vVVc/1/

I changed the function in your javascript to:

```
function swapIC0(n) {        
    document.getElementById('IMG_20').src = arICImages0[n];
}
```